Sample average of L2 estimator
Suppose I am interested in estimating a parameter $\theta = E[f_0(X)]$. I have an estimator for $f_0$ such that $\|f_0-\hat{f}_n\|_{L_2}^2\xrightarrow{P}0  $ . Is it correct to state that $|\frac{1}{n}\sum \hat{f}_n(X_i)-E[f_0(X)]|\xrightarrow{P} 0$?
My proof is the following:
\begin{align}
\left| \frac{1}{n} \sum \hat{f}_n(X_i) - \mathbb{E}[f_0(X)] \right| 
&= \left| \frac{1}{n} \sum \hat{f}_n(X_i) - \mathbb{E}[\hat{f}_n(X)] + \mathbb{E}[\hat{f}_n(X) - f_0(x)] \right| \\
&\leq \left| \frac{1}{n} \sum \hat{f}_n(X_i) - \mathbb{E}[\hat{f}_n(X)] \right| + \left| \mathbb{E}[\hat{f}_n(X) - f_0(X)] \right| \\
&\leq \left| \frac{1}{n} \sum \hat{f}_n(X_i) - \mathbb{E}[\hat{f}_n(X)] \right| + \mathbb{E}[|\hat{f}_n(X) - f_0(X)|] \\
&= \left| \frac{1}{n} \sum \hat{f}_n(X_i) - \mathbb{E}[\hat{f}_n(X)] \right| + \|\hat{f}_n - f_0\|_{L_1} \\
&\leq \left| \frac{1}{n} \sum \hat{f}_n(x_i) - \mathbb{E}[\hat{f}_n(X)] \right| + \|\hat{f}_n - f_0\|_{L_2}\xrightarrow{P} 0 
\end{align}
where the first goes to zero by LLN and the second by assumption. Am I going wrong somewhere?

The proof is correct for a fixed function $\hat{f}$ as long as the first moment $\mathbb{E}[\hat{f}(X)]$ exists and the second moment $\mathbb{E}[\hat{f}(X)^2]<+\infty$. The main issue is that estimators are sequences $\{\hat{f}_n\}$, thus I need to have a uniform LLN even though I might be able to apply LLN for every single $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ (pointiwse convergence does not imply uniform). Thus I need to verify what class my estimators come from and make sure to have a so called Glivenko Cantelli class that is guaranted uninform convergence to zero.
